# Excluding a certain range of bins in a matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, data-visualization

I'm using matplotlib to look at how wins are distributed based on betting odds for the MLB. The issue is that because betting odds are either >= 100 or <= -100, there's a big gap in the middle of my histogram.

Is there any way to exclude certain bins (specifically anything between -100 and 100) so that the bars of the chart flow more smoothly?

[Link to current histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MCzM.png)

Here's the code I have right now:

```
num_bins = 20
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

n, bins, patches = ax.hist(winner_odds_df['WinnerOdds'], num_bins, 
range=range_of_winner_odds)

ax.set_xlabel('Betting Odds')
ax.set_ylabel('Win Frequency')
ax.set_title('Histogram of Favorite Win Frequency Based on Betting Odds (2018)')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: try using `bins = 'auto'`. maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could break your chart's x-axis as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html), by plotting on two different axes that are made to visually look like one plot. The essential part, rewritten to apply to the x-axis instead of the y-axis, is:

```
f, (axl, axr) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

# plot the same data on both axes
axl.hist(winner_odds_df['WinnerOdds'], num_bins)
axr.hist(winner_odds_df['WinnerOdds'], num_bins)

# zoom-in / limit the view to different portions of the data
axl.set_xlim(-500, -100)  # outliers only
axr.set_xlim(100, 500)  # most of the data

# hide the spines between axl and axr
axl.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axr.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

axr.yaxis.tick_right()
# How much space to leave between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.15)
```

See the linked document for how to polish this by adding diagonal break lines. The basic version produced by the code above then looks like this:
[image: Normal distribution with broken x-axis]